# Auth0 Does not work from inside Docker container + Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, auth0

I have developed a golang application using Auth0 for user authentication, I have also developed a frontend app. On my local machine everything works fine. Now I want to deploy the app via docker on AWS elastic beanstalk. 
I build my docker image and run it, but Auth0 does not work anymore. I get the following error when I want to validate the authtoken send by a user:

```
Token is not valid  <nil>
Token err: Get https://xxx.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

This happens running the docker image on my local machine as well as on elastic beanstalk. However, if I just run go run main.go, everything works fine.
Any ideas why ? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check docker image you use for hosting your application. It should include registration for root certificate.

You can find some image that includes that certificate or add them dynamicaly as described in this blog post - https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried to generate a self signed certificate, but I guess that results in a unknown authority, since I still get the same error. Where can I get the correct certificate from ?

Comment: You need to buy it or use service like letsencrypt.